# Prove that if $\lim a_{n} = \infty,$ then $\lim (-a_{n}) = -\infty.$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Here is what I have so far:

It is given that: $$\forall{\alpha}>0 \;\; \exists{N_{\alpha}}\;:\;\forall{n>N_{\alpha}}\Rightarrow a_{n}>\alpha$$ and we wish to verify that: $$\ \forall{\alpha}>0 \;\; \exists{M_{\alpha}}\;:\;\forall{n>M_{\alpha}}\Rightarrow -a_{n}<-\alpha$$
I believe the next step is to choose an arbitrary value for $\alpha$. Then see if we can determine an $M_{\alpha}$ based on what we find by plugging that arbritrary $\alpha$ into what is given. The problem is I am running into is that I have no inclination about what $\alpha>0$ to choose. I tried $\frac{1}{\epsilon}$ but that did not seem to work.

Comment: Your second version is equivalent to the first.

Comment: You can take $M_\alpha=N_\alpha$ because
$$a_n>\alpha\Rightarrow a_n-\alpha>0\Rightarrow -\alpha>-a_n\Rightarrow-a_n<-\alpha.$$

Comment: Do not hesitate to ask for any further clarification!

Answer (score 1):

Yes you are on the right track, indeed from here since we are given that $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}a_n=\infty$ (note that we don't need to assume $\alpha>0$):

$$\forall{\alpha} \;\; \exists{N_{\alpha}}\;:\;\forall{n>N_{\alpha}}\implies a_{n}>\alpha$$

we obtain

$$\forall{\alpha} \;\; \exists{N_{\alpha}}\;:\;\forall{n>N_{\alpha}}\implies-a_{n}<-\alpha$$

that is $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}(-a_n)=-\infty$.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}a_n=\infty.$$

Let $M>0$ be given. Then we have $N\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $a_n>M$ for all $n\geq N$.

Note that for any $n\geq N$, $-a_n<-M$. Thus, we have $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}(-a_n)=-\infty$ since the definition of it is
$$\forall M>0 \hspace{3mm} \exists N\in \mathbb{N}\text{ such that } (-a_n)<-M.$$

Comment: The assumption $M>0$ is not wrong but it is unnecessary for the definition.

Comment: @gimusi  Could you tell me why $M>0$ is unnecessary for the definition?

Comment: Because when we state in the definition  $\forall M\, \exists n...$ it suffices to cover also the case $M>0$. Therefore it is not wrong of course but itbus not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

*It is given that: $$\forall{\alpha}>0 \;\; \exists{N_{\alpha}}\;:\;\forall{n>N_{\alpha}}\Rightarrow a_{n}>\alpha\tag{1}$$ and we wish to verify that: $$\ \forall{\alpha}>0 \;\; \exists{M_{\alpha}}\;:\;\forall{n>M_{\alpha}}\Rightarrow -a_{n}<-\alpha\tag{2}$$*

Take $M_\alpha=N_\alpha$. Then

$$\begin{aligned}
n>M_\alpha &\Rightarrow n>N_\alpha&&(\text{because } M_\alpha=N_\alpha)\\
&\Rightarrow a_n>\alpha&&(\text{by } (1))\\
&\Rightarrow -a_n<-\alpha&&(\text{multiplying by }-1)
\end{aligned}$$

This proves $(2)$.